# Reporting and pulling values from a text field string to fire up a class and present a chart

Tags: c#, string, function, class, text

Please bear with me - I'm a relative newbie to .net.

I want to create a free-form report where the client can drop in a piece of code like <%=(NetPromo("1871"))%> (as I used in a classic asp script to fire up a function) into the text to run code to generate a chart.

The reporting & chart generation I have squared away - I just can't work out how to extract parts of the long text string to pass a value back to generate the charts. I'm using c# .net web forms.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide what you have tried?

Comment: I really don't have anything to show. I have something similar using classic asp pulling text from a file which contained markers like <%=demo(1234)%> dotted around in it to fire off functions to generate different charts which works very well. I just can't figure out how to do the same in .net. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, for your problem, at all but have you tried using for example:

```
string inputYouWant = textBox1.Text; 
inputYouWant = inputYouWant.Replace("oldChar","newValue"); 
//If the input string isn't the way you want it
```

This way you should get your input as string if you use TextBoxes in your Form.

Best Regards ;)

Comment: Reading your comments, I realize I probably misunderstood your question :facepalm: Maybe my answer still helps you anyhow :-P